# 2D avi animation generation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video, avi

I made a 2D AVI animation in Matlab, there are one green dot and one blue dot moving along a line into different directions. But now i want to add into this AVI animation video another dot, which move in a random path together with the other two dots, what should i write codes here now ? attached below is my codes.  Thanks very much for your help!

```
clc; clear;
%time steps

N=20;
%start position of one moving object

x_pos=10;

y_pos=10;

x1_pos=100;

y1_pos=100;
%speed of the moving object

speed_x=3;

speed_y=2;

speed_x1=-4;

speed_y1=-2;
%ini white image with size 100 x 150

image=ones(100,150,3);
%initialization of videowriter

outputVideo = VideoWriter('test.avi');

outputVideo.FrameRate = 5; %set frame rate of the image

open(outputVideo)  
%drawing a moving object on an image plane and creating the video

size=2;

for i=1:N
%update states of moving object

x_pos=x_pos+speed_x;

y_pos=y_pos+speed_y;

x1_pos=x1_pos+speed_x1;

y1_pos=y1_pos+speed_y1;
%draw the measurement on the image using a green point with specific size size=4;

image((x_pos-size/2):(x_pos+size/2),(y_pos-size/2):(y_pos+size/2),1)=0;

image((x_pos-size/2):(x_pos+size/2),(y_pos-size/2):(y_pos+size/2),3)=0;

image((x1_pos-size/2):(x1_pos+size/2),(y1_pos-size/2):(y1_pos+size/2),2)=0;

image((x1_pos-size/2):(y1_pos+size/2),(y1_pos-size/2):(y1_pos+size/2),1)=0;
%give the image to the video writer object
writeVideo(outputVideo,image)

end

close(outputVideo);
```

Comment: Er, what does "random" meaning? does it begin at random point and move randomly?

Comment: @HunterJiang Yes, it is. In the same video image, moving together with the other two, not in a line path,  but move randomly

Answer (score 0):

These codes may help, and new codes are between "****" lines.

```
clc; clear;
%time steps

N=20;
%start position of one moving object

x_pos=10;

y_pos=10;

x1_pos=100;

y1_pos=100;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%set the start point
rdx_pos=50+floor((rand()-0.5)*20);

rdy_pos=50+floor((rand()-0.5)*20);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%speed of the moving object

speed_x=3;

speed_y=2;

speed_x1=-4;

speed_y1=-2;

%ini white image with size 100 x 150

image=ones(100,150,3);
%initialization of videowriter

outputVideo = VideoWriter('test.avi');

outputVideo.FrameRate = 5; %set frame rate of the image

open(outputVideo)  
%drawing a moving object on an image plane and creating the video

size=2;

for i=1:N
%update states of moving object

x_pos=x_pos+speed_x;

y_pos=y_pos+speed_y;

x1_pos=x1_pos+speed_x1;

y1_pos=y1_pos+speed_y1;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%set the new point   

rdx_pos=rdx_pos+floor((rand()-0.5)*5);

rdy_pos=rdy_pos+floor((rand()-0.5)*5);

%check the point 
if (rdx_pos >150) rdx_pos=150; end
if (rdx_pos <1) rdx_pos=1; end
if (rdy_pos >100) rdx_pos=100; end
if (rdy_pos <1) rdx_pos=1; end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%draw the measurement on the image using a green point with specific size size=4;

image((x_pos-size/2):(x_pos+size/2),(y_pos-size/2):(y_pos+size/2),1)=0;

image((x_pos-size/2):(x_pos+size/2),(y_pos-size/2):(y_pos+size/2),3)=0;

image((x1_pos-size/2):(x1_pos+size/2),(y1_pos-size/2):(y1_pos+size/2),2)=0;

image((x1_pos-size/2):(y1_pos+size/2),(y1_pos-size/2):(y1_pos+size/2),1)=0;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%output image
image((rdx_pos-size/2):(rdx_pos+size/2),(rdy_pos-size/2):(rdy_pos+size/2),2)=0;

image((rdx_pos-size/2):(rdx_pos+size/2),(rdy_pos-size/2):(rdy_pos+size/2),1)=0;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%give the image to the video writer object
writeVideo(outputVideo,image)

end

close(outputVideo);
```

Comment: I'll have class in ten minutes so I can't check the part "check the point" carefully, but your code must have them(not only the random point but also point & point1).

Comment: no problem. If there is any question with my code plz leave a comment and I will check it a.s.a.p (After my class).  @Jing Huang